# Temporary video streaming URL

Tags: php, video, yii

I am trying to create an url to provide a video only one time.
I will use that as an src for the video tag.

The idea is.
Create an temporary and valid url.
When the page is open I check if the page is valid (there is a temporary table with valid registers), get the data, delete the temporary register and open the file.

The problem is, if i delete the temporary register, after I get the data, the video streaming does not works.

It seems that it does not acts like a file descriptor, when, after it is open, even if i delete the node it keeps open.

The code that i am using is:

```
    $temp=Temporaryvideo::model()->findByAttributes(array("video_id" => "$content", "hash" => "$key"));

    if(count($temp)==1){

        $video=Video::model()->findByPk($content);
        $filename=$video->attributes['video_url'];

        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: -1');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Cache-Control: private', false); // required for certain browsers ); 
        header('Content-Type: video/mp4');

        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("videos/$filename"));
        //$temp->delete();
        readfile("videos/$filename");
    }
```

That works fine until i delete the register from the database. Is there a way to make the url valid only once?
I want to do that to avoid people from downloading the video. I know that there is other ways for them to get the video, but that will avoid some people to do that.

Changing the content-type to application/octet-stream solves that issue, but i cannot go forward or to the begin of the video.

Comment: probably a good workaround is with a logic delete, instead of deleting the record, you could update some sort of flag to tell you that in future requests, the url is not valid anymore

Comment: @PabloFlores, But that will have the same effect, if the flag is marked I would not return data/open the file.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the best solution was to use

```
$temp=Temporaryvideo::model()->findByAttributes(array("video_id" => "$content", "hash" => "$key"));

if(count($temp)==1){

    $video=Video::model()->findByPk($content);
    $filename=$video->attributes['video_url'];

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: -1');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false); // required for certain browsers ); 
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("videos/$filename"));
    $temp->delete();
    readfile("videos/$filename");
}
```

That way the url is invalidate and the streaming continues. If you try to go forward or backward on the video, it will break.